# How to fetch and display JSON data by id or name on screen (Android)

Tags: android, json, android-edittext, android-button

Consider:

```java
      public RetroPhoto(Integer id, String email, String first_name, String last_name, String avatar) {
        this.id = id;
        this.email = email;
        this.first_name = first_name;
        this.last_name = last_name;
        this.avatar = avatar;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getFirst_name() {
        return first_name;
    }

    public void setFirst_name(String first_name) {
        this.first_name = first_name;
    }

    public String getLast_name() {
        return last_name;
    }

    public void setLast_name(String last_name) {
        this.last_name = last_name;
    }

    public String getAvatar() {
        return avatar;
    }

    public void setAvatar(String avatar) {
        this.avatar = avatar;
    }
}
```

Suppose I have an edittext and button on the screen.
I have to fetch the details of a person by ID through JSON data.

So when I type the id as "1", it should display the details of that particular person from JSON data below the button as textview. What will be the logic for it?

The above is JSON.

Comment: share your json

Comment: I have shared see above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are getting full JSON content, you need to parse through the list and get the JSON object related to the person id.

In the onClick, you can get the id by

```
// Probably check if it's a valid number and non-empty
int id = parseInt(editTextId.getText().toString())

retrofitInstance.apiCall.enqueue ......
....
onResponse (){
    List<RetroPhoto> list = response.body();
    boolean idFound = false;
    for (int i=0; i< list.size(); i++) {
        if (list.get(i).getId() == id) {
            // You can get details of person here
            idFound = true;
        }
    }
    if (idFound == false) {
        // Toast invalid id message
    }
}
...
```

Since you are using [Retrofit](https://square.github.io/retrofit/).

Comment: private static final String BASE_URL = "https://api.myjson.com/bins/ ";  // my base url.           below is my interface --                                                                                                              public interface GetDataService {

    @GET("14rw00")
    Call<List<RetroPhoto>> getAllPhotos();
}

Comment: if I have to display the details in textview .how can I display it?textId.setText()?what should I write under setText?

Comment: I found it...txt1.setText(list.get(i).getEmail());..thanks a lot Monster brain

Comment: I have also one last question ...how to clear the previous id details .see if I want to display the another id details .what to do for replacing old with new(another) id details ?

Comment: you have seen I have only 6 ids in jSON data ..what to do when user typed id as "7" other than 6 ids????how should I validate

Comment: I have tried this method.... if(list.get(i).getId()!= id&&list.get(i).getId()==null)
                                {
                                    Toast.makeText(IdActivity.this,"NO ID............",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()   }//////it crashes every time when I click on button

Comment: put a boolean isValid = false; before for loop, then if found valid id, set isValid = true. Then after for loop, if(!isValid) { Toast("Invalid person ID");  }

Comment: "before for loop, then if found valid id, set isValid = true" ....can you provide me the proper code??

Comment: it worked....but when I'm keeping edit text null and clicked ,it crashes

Comment: Of course, when parsing empty string it will crash. You have to check before parsing.
If you find the answer helpful, please check the tick mark.

Comment: I got it..instead using of "int id = parseInt(editTextId.getText().toString())
"......I used ...final int id;
                int id1;
                try {
                    String idedittext = edit1.getText().toString();
                    id1 = Integer.parseInt(idedittext);
                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                    id1 =0 ;
                }

                id = id1;

Answer (score 0):

When you got the value which you want to display, then there you can use this:

```
EditText mEdit;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    mEdit = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittext);

    callAPI();
}

public void callAPI(){

   /** Do your API call and retrieve the value/id **/

   mEdit.setText("value from API")
}
```

Comment: how to fetch the id?see I have only design edit text and button.i haven't written any logic.i have only described my idea above.can you be more specific

Comment: I'm unclear with your code .I have added my json data above.base url and interface method in "MONSTER BRAIN"comment section please have a look at it

Answer (score 0):

First things first. You need to use network libraries such as Retrofit, Volley, etc. for fetching JSON content from the server through an API. Retrofit is faster than Volley. Use the [POST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_%28HTTP%29) method to post the id to the server and from the API side you need to fetch data based on that id and convert it as JSON and send back the response.

Go through this link for further details. [https://square.github.io/retrofit](https://square.github.io/retrofit/)

Comment: I'm using retrofit.i don't want the POST method I want GET method .please read my description above what I actually want

Comment: I want the actual logic of onClick(MainActivity).see I have my instance method and interface method in my project.

Comment: I'm unclear with your code .I have added my json data above.base url and interface method in "MONSTER BRAIN"comment section please have a look at it

Comment: Please add your retrofit call, What actually you are doing in onResponse?.

Comment: I have got the solution ...monster brain helped ....the above code provided by monster brain is correct...the thing is he haven't provided the whole code...those are understandable code(retrofit calll)....